# How reverse my List in C?

Tags: c, list, reverse

How reverse my list ??

My function PrintList print: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

But, I want: 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.

```
struct Node
{
    TElement Element;
    Position    Next;
};

Position Header( List L )
{
   return L;
}

Position Advance( Position P )
{
    return P->Next;
}

void PrintList( const List L ){

    Position P = Header( L );
    if( IsEmpty( L ) )
        printf( "Empty list\n" );
    else
    {
        do
        {
            P = Advance( P );
            printf( "%d ", Retrieve( P ) );
        } while( !IsLast( P, L ) );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main()
{
    List L1;
    Position P;
    int i;

    P = Header( L1 );
    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        Insert( i, L1, P );
        P = Advance( P );
    }
    printf(" List L1: ");
    PrintList( L1 );
}
```

Comment: What is `Header`? What is `Advance`? ....

Comment: Position Header( List L )
        {
            return L;
        }

Comment: Perhaps edit the question would be better

Comment: Position Advance( Position P )
        {
            return P->Next;
        }

Comment: struct Node
        {
            TElement Element;
            Position    Next;
        };

Comment: Please edit the question

Comment: What about the rest? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try inserting the elements at the beginning of a new list sequentially!

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer:** since you have a singly linked list and want to print it backwards, you need to walk the list collecting items into another structure (an array below) and then walk that backwards:

```
#define LARGE_ENOUGH 1024

void PrintList(const List L) {

    if (IsEmpty(L)) {
        printf("Empty list\n");
        return;
    }

    Position P = Header(L);
    TElement Elements[LARGE_ENOUGH];
    int i = 0;

    do {
        P = Advance(P);
        Elements[i++] =  Retrieve(P);
    } while (!IsLast(P, L));

    while (--i >= 0) {
        printf( "%d ", Elements[i]);
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}
```

**PRODUCES**

```
> ./a.out
 List L1: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
>
```

**The long answer:** I pieced together the missing parts of your code from this [list.h](http://augustus.gobics.de/binaries/scripts/compileSpliceCands/list.h) & [list.c](http://augustus.gobics.de/binaries/scripts/compileSpliceCands/list.c) and made a few changes along the way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int TElement;

typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;
typedef PtrToNode List;
typedef PtrToNode Position;

struct Node {
    TElement Element;
    Position Next;
};

Position Header(List L)
{
    return L;
}

int IsLast(Position P, List L) 
{
    return P->Next == NULL;
}

int IsEmpty(List L) 
{
    return L->Next == NULL;
}

Position Advance(Position P)
{
    return P->Next;
}

TElement Retrieve(Position P)  {
    return P->Element;
}

int FatalError (char *ErrorMessage)  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", ErrorMessage);
    exit(1);
}

void Insert(TElement X, List L, Position P )  {
    Position TmpCell = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (TmpCell == NULL) {
        FatalError("Out of space!");
    }

    TmpCell->Element = X;
    TmpCell->Next = P->Next;
    P->Next = TmpCell;
}

#define LARGE_ENOUGH 1024

void PrintList(const List L) {

    if (IsEmpty(L)) {
        printf("Empty list\n");
        return;
    }

    Position P = Header(L);
    TElement Elements[LARGE_ENOUGH];
    int i = 0;

    do {
        P = Advance(P);
        Elements[i++] =  Retrieve(P);
    } while (!IsLast(P, L));

    while (--i >= 0) {
        printf( "%d ", Elements[i]);
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}

int main() {
    List L1 = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node));

    Position P = Header(L1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Insert(i, L1, P);
        P = Advance(P);
    }

    printf(" List L1: ");
    PrintList(L1);
}
```

The above is for the benefit of others who might like to take a crack at answering your question.

Answer (score -2):

```
int main()
{
    List L1;
    Position P;
    int i;

    P = Header( L1 );
    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        Insert( i, L1, P );
        P = Advance( P );
    }
    printf(" List L1: ");
    PrintList( L1 );
}
```

Comment: This answer is meaningless

Comment: @EdHeal, I don't believe this is an answer but rather the OP to providing more of his source code.  I've added it to the source in the original question and reformatted everything.